# How do I modify the elements.xml for the default.aspx page using powershell or C#?

Tags: 2010, powershell, xslt-list-view-web-part

On SharePoint 2010, I have a site template solution created by saving a site as a template.  Recently I modified the template in Visual Studio - I needed to change the markup for several XsltListViewWebParts (changed the BaseViewId from 0 to 1) on the default.aspx page.  I found that the markup that I needed to change actually lived in the elements.xml file associated with the default.aspx file.

I would like to make the same change to hundreds of sites that have already been created from this site template.  I have figured out how to get at the default.aspx file from the SPWeb.Files collection, but I cannot figure out how to get at the elements.xml file.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once created, the pages really have no connection to the elements file anymore.

You could probably open a SPLimitedWebPartManager with the URL to the page, find the correct webpart and change a property on it though! More of that here: http://www.kentd.com/2013/03/06/update-web-part-on-a-page-using-powershell-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: This put me on the right path - found what I needed in the XsltListViewWebPart.XmlDefinition property.